# Understanding CylindricalAlgebraicDecompose command in Maple

Tags: maple

I'm new with Maple and I'm trying to follow the tutorial about the 'CylindricalAlgebraicDecompose' command.

My question is probably very simple for anyone who knows how to use the program.

All I tried to do was to follow the following link and to get the same results as in the link (I added below the link and a screenshot from the link of the results I tried to get:

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=RegularChains%2FSemiAlgebraicSetTools%2FCylindricalAlgebraicDecompose

[image]

But this is what I actually got in my computer:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I'm not getting the same results and what should I change in the commands?

Thanks

Comment: This is a question about Maple usage rather than mathematics (although it might well have not appeared to the OP as a syntax and usage problem). It would be better suited to www.stackoverflow.com or www.mapleprimes.com .

Comment: That's why I tagged only 'maple' and no other group. I didn't know it matters if I'm in mathematics or stackoverflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you entered (in 2D Input mode),

```
F := [xy - 1];
```

where that contains the name `xy` instead of the product `x*y`.

In both 1D (plaintext) Maple Notation input mode as well as 2D Input mode you could enter it like,

```
F := [x*y - 1];
```

with an explicit multiplication symbol.

In 2D Input mode you could also use a space between the names intead of the `*` symbol, which denotes the multiplication implicitly. That is what is being done in the actual Help page image you posted.

The visual cue that one has used such implicit multiplication in 2D Input mode is subtle -- a slight space between the letters x and y in this case.

Failure to recognize 2D Input implicit multiplication is a common problem, mostly because of the lack of visual cues.

If you have problems with 2D Input mode, and the Document interface, then you can change those to 1D Maple Notation and the Worksheet interface as a pair of preferences under the Tools->Options menubar item.

Comment: Great! it works. thanks!